# Help With Code Coverage

Tags: apex, trigger

new developer and I am struggling with getting 100% code coverage on a test class. I have written a class to count tasks with unique subline lines and then update a field on a custom object with the count. Basically, all code below the For(task t : taskList) loop is not running.  The method is being called from a trigger handler and the test method is inserting relationship_owners and contacts from a data factory.

Here is the method

```
public static void uniqueRelationshipOwnerEmails(List<relationship_owner__c> roList){
    //count the unique emails  that have been sent by a relationship owner
    // add all contacts associated with relationship owner to map.         
    Map<id, Contact> contactMap = new Map<Id, Contact>([SELECT Id,
                                                        New_Relationship_Owner1__c
                                                        FROM Contact
                                                        WHERE New_Relationship_owner1__c IN : roList]);
    system.debug('Contacts found = ' + contactMap.size());
    //put tasks where whoId is in the contact map into a new map
    List<Task> taskList = [SELECT Id, WhoId,Subject
                           FROM Task 
                           WHERE WhoId IN :contactMap.keySet()
                           AND Subject LIKE '%Pardot List Email%'];
    system.debug('Tasks Found  and added to map = ' + taskList.size());
    //use set to dedupe the list
    Map<Id, Set<String>> subjectLineMap = new Map<Id, Set<String>>();

    for(task t : taskList){
        Id ownerId = contactMap.get(t.WhoId).New_Relationship_Owner1__c;            
        if(!subjectLineMap.containsKey(ownerId)){
            subjectLineMap.put(ownerId, new Set<String>());              

        }            
    }
    system.debug('Map size   =' + subjectLineMap.size());
    system.debug('map values =' + subjectLineMap.values());
    system.debug('map keys   =' + subjectLineMap.Keyset());
    for(relationship_owner__c r : roList){
        r.Unique_Emails_Sent__c = subjectLineMap.get(r.Id).size();
        roList.add(r);

    }
    insert(roList);         



}
```

and here is the test method.

```
@isTest
static void uniqueEmailTest(){
    TestDataFactory.createRelationshipOwnerandInfuencer(5, 1);
    List<relationship_owner__C> ownerTestList = [SELECT id, Unique_Emails_Sent__c From relationship_owner__c];
    //update ownerTestList;
    //get the contacts and assign them tasks
    List<Contact> influencers = [SELECT Id FROM Contact];        
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    for(Contact c : influencers){
       Task t = new Task(Subject = 'Pardot List Email 1', WhoId = c.Id);
        tasks.add(t);
    }
    insert tasks;        
    system.debug('task size' + tasks.size());
    update ownerTestList;
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You don't really need 100% coverage, honestly I have rarely seen classes covered 100% when building a large scale application. I do try to get more than 90% to accommodate any low coverage classes but most of the times anything around 80 - 85 should be considered good. If you have coverage sufficiently above 75%, then you should be fine. What is your current coverage as of now? **Btw** - I don't see your test class calling the method which you are trying to cover.

Comment: one way to help think about testmethods is the [Given-When-Then](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/GivenWhenThen.html) model which forces you to think through in comments what you are trying to test and then you can code the testmethod accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to insert `Contact` records (and `relationship_owner__C` records) in your test before this line for this query to return any results and so create the `Task` records needed to cause the code under test to run:

```
List<Contact> influencers = [SELECT Id FROM Contact];
```

By design, unit tests don't see most types of records that are in the org: you have to explicitly add records in your test.

(I presume `uniqueRelationshipOwnerEmails` is called from a trigger?)

The point of tests is to confirm the behavior of the code under test: coverage is just an indicator, not a sufficient condition. So do add additional logic to your test (typically queries and asserts) that confirm the expected effects of the code under test.

Comment: I am sorry I  was not clear in my original post.  The method I called from the testDataFactory created 5 relationship owners and 1 contact per owner.  I will edit my original post. And the method is called from a trigger handler.  Right now I have 66% code coverage.